# Command history in R

Tags: ide, r

Is there any IDE -from the ones supporting R-, that gives access to the command history (at least to the current session's commands)? Or is there a way to get a (character or expression) vector with those commands in R?

For those of you that have been using MATLAB, I mean something like the [Command History](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/command_history_overview.gif) window there..

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
history(Inf)
```

opens a window similar to that in MATLAB.

Answer (score 8):

```
savehistory('file')
myhistory <- scan('file','character')
```

Might do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend to use Emacs with [ESS (Emacs speaks Statistic)](http://ess.r-project.org/)

Comment: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Command-History describes the command history support of ESS.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse with Stat-ET plugin will get you command history window and object browser.

Comment: I don't believe that Stat-ET has an object browser.  Where do you see that?

Comment: Go to Window > Show View > Object Browser

Answer (score 4):

The OS X GUI for R has a very nice command history mechanism built in.  It works well with multi-line commands (e.g. long function definitions), and you can browse through the history in a pane on the side of the window.

Answer (score 3):

The command `history()` will recall the last 25 used commands, whereas `history(max.show=Inf)`will get back all previous ones. If you are using RStudio on top of your R distro, `CTRL + UP` will give you the list of all previous commands.