# Get last command from history as text string in R

Tags: r, input-history

Is there a way to print the last executed command from as a text string in R? I've tried `history(1)`, but in RStudio this just changes the focus to the the "History" pane. I've tried `print(history(1))` and `cat(history(1))', both of which return nothing. Here is what I get in the console when I try these commands:

```
> history(1)
> history(1)[1]
NULL
> cat(history(1))
> print(history(1))
NULL
```

I'm hoping to avoid the `savehistory('file'); myhistory <- scan('file','character')` solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749390/command-history-in-r).

Comment: to return as a string rather than a call, replace relevant line in function of accepted answer by `if( length(ret) == 1 ) return(deparse(ret[[1]])) else return(deparse(ret))`. If it's not clear enough tell me and I'll reopen. Or just use `deparse` on the output.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the keyword I needed to search was "call" and not "command". Your edit to the answer to the other post gave some funky behavior when the argument to `last.call` was anything other than a single value (e.g. `last.call(n = 2:5)`), so I changed `ret <- rev(cmds)[n]; if(length(ret) == 1) return(ret[[1]]) else return(ret)}; return(NULL)` to `if(length(ret) == 1) a <- ret[1] else a <- ret; out <- sapply(a, deparse); out`.

Comment: As a side note, what does the line `return(NULL)` do in the original code? If the preceding `if` statement were `FALSE` wouldn't the function return `NULL` even without `return(NULL)`?